# Managed instance group shutdown script alternative

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have running VM´s inside a MIG. I need to fully drain all the data from the VM´s before the different nodes are shut down by order of the autoscaler. I tried with the shutdown script but the autoscaler only gives me 90 seconds and I need more time so the shutdown script to complete the work. Does anyone know if there´s like a pre-shutdown script or something similar? Or maybe a way to delay those 90 seconds? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript), the shutdown script has a limited time period to run. If the script takes longer than this time period to complete, the instance automatically stops and all running tasks are ended. If you shut down or restart an instance by making a request to the guest [operating system](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#stop-vm-through-os) with the **sudo shutdown** command, the limit does not apply.

Shutdown scripts have a limited amount of time to finish running before the instance stops. Compute Engine executes shutdown scripts only on a best-effort basis. In rare cases, Compute Engine cannot guarantee that the shutdown script will complete.

The shutdown period usually lasts at least 90 seconds. However this timer cannot be extended by a shutdown script or cannot be extended by any customizable configuration as the virtual machine will be forcefully terminated past the 90 seconds grace period by the system. Unfortunately, there are no alternative solutions in regards to your use case.

**Note :** There are several feature requests like [Configurable instance shutdown time](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904817) and  [Autoscaling - shutdown script custom invokation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904817) for this, but unlikely that will be implemented soon.